# Materials not applied after importing .obj (ShapeNet)

Tags: materials, import, color

I want to use Blender to generate a dataset of videos. As a basis I want to use [ShapeNet](https://www.shapenet.org/taxonomy-viewer).

When importing the `.obj` file, blender also correctly loads all the materials from the `.mtl` file. By that I mean that they are listed in the material tab of the properties window. But for some objects the materials are not correctly applied to the surfaces.

Example: The object with the ID `3dw.e480a15c22ee438753388b7ae6bc11aa` should look like this:

[image: preview of 3dw.e480a15c22ee438753388b7ae6bc11aa on the shapenet website]

However, if I just import the file in blender, the rendering will look something like that:

[image: rendered image]

So, the colors of the knobs work, also the textures of the pillows, but the rest of the colors don't.

What seems strange to me is, that I cannot select the different faces and color them myself in blender. Also, if I move the main part of the bed, a frame of lines will remain there. Maybe this has something to do with the problem:

[image]

Similar problems occur for many objects. For example `3dw.b1696ffd98c753ccea88a0a7eb1222bb`. There, the problem with the frame of lines does not occur and I can color the airplane afterwards, but it somehow does not load the materials when imported.

How can it be, that it works for some objects but for others it doesn't?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: I don't think so. I did not export the model but start with an `.obj` and a `.mtl` file. The materials are all listed in the materials tab of the properties window, they are just not applied to the faces they ought to be.

Answer (score 2):

This problem with the materials in Blender with the ShapeNet objects seems to be a common one. This worked for me (I used ShapeNetSem):

You can convert your .obj models to .gltf format using the [obj2gltf](https://github.com/CesiumGS/obj2gltf) package. Be sure that the ShapeNet textures can be found during converting: I had to put all the .jpg texture images inside the same directory as the .obj and corresponding .mtl files (you can see which textures are needed for a model by opening its .mtl file in a text editor). Then import your .gltf models in Blender. They should now load properly.

On top of that, you can also try to turn off *Backface Culling* and *Auto Smooth*, in Blender. This wasn't necessary in my case, but I've read it helps for some people.